# How to send data from React to Django API

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to add some data to an database with django. As frontend I use React.

Thus, `fetch` request is as follows:

```
const data = {
  name: formData.name,
  email: formData.email,
  title: formData.title,
  message: formData.message
};

fetch("/some/some_view/", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
  debugger;
  console.log('Success:', data);
})
  .catch((error) => {
  debugger;
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

And in Django I have view as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=400)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #TODO: Add security
        item = json.loads(request.POST.get('body'), object_hook=json_util.object_hook)
        pdb.set_trace()
        return HttpJsonOk()
```

In `request.POST` I get the data that I want to send as follows:

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"name":"dsdsd","email":"dsdsd@dsds.com","title":"dsds jflj ","message":"dlkj lksj kmsdkk fljs m"}': [u'']}>
```

But I expect it to be in `request.POST.get('body')`, but there I do not get anything.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you check network tab request ? Is this server side error? or client side?

Comment: try to use `request.body` instead of `request.POST.get('body')`

Comment: @LinnTroll That works. But I want the data in `request.POST.get('body')`. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Boky in this case you need change on JS side.
Change content type to `x-www-form-urlencoded` and change body to qs format.

Comment: "But I want the data in request.POST.get('body')" => why ??? LinnTroll gave you the proper technical way to parse json POST content. You've tested it and it works. What's your problem ???

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST` contains the result of parsing `request.body` as form-encoded content. Note that the *real* request content is actually in `request.body` (print it out from your view to find out what it looks like).

Now your react front is posting json content, not form-encoded content, so you CAN NOT get those data from `request.POST` - as you can obviously tell from what the querydict looks like:

```
 <QueryDict: {u'{"name":"dsdsd","email":"dsdsd@dsds.com","title":"dsds jflj ","message":"dlkj lksj kmsdkk fljs m"}': [u'']}>
```

As you can see, the parsing failed (since it's not form-encoded), leading to the whole submitted json being used as key, with no associated value.

IOW, LinnTroll's suggestion is actually the proper solution - the one that is used by any REST framework (DRF, restless etc) FWIW -: just use `request.body`, period.

> But I want the data in request.POST.get('body')

You cant, because there's no 'body' key in `request.POST`. Period.